# Rails 4 AR `from` different than rails 3?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, arel, with-clause

In rails 3 if I write: `Model.from('models')` arel generates the following sql:

```
select "models".* from models
```

In rails 4 the same arel generates the following sql:

```
select "models".* from 'models', NULL
```

The table name is wrapped in quotes and ', NULL' is appended. How do I use arel to give me the same results as in rails 3?

I was leveraging the original behavior so I could run a fairly complex `with recursive` query against postgres. In rails4, postgres is choking when it gets to the single quote preceding value I give `from`.

Is there a better way to do a `with recursive` query? Or, is there a way to query with arel so it works as before?

Comment: I'm not able to duplicate that error you're seeing. Using an app with a vendors table I see the same SQL statement on both 3.2 & 4 with `Vendor.from('vendors').to_sql` which results in `#=> "SELECT \"vendors\".* FROM vendors"`. Could you share more of your complex query?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not even using the complex query at this point, just a simple query like the one you tried. Still, I'm getting a different `to_sql`. Maybe version difference? Rails 4.0.0, pg 0.15.1. Any other relevant gems?

Comment: @DanReedy aha! thanks for the sanity check. This is being caused by the squeel gem. Must be an incompatibility, since I get the expected behavior when I remove it from my project. I'll take it up with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an incompatibility with the [squeel gem](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) (the master branch as of today).

**EDIT** I've sent a [pull request](https://github.com/ernie/squeel/pull/257) to squeel's master branch. Fixes the issue for me.

**EDIT 2:** Merged into master

Comment: Shame :( One of my favourite gems!

Comment: @Damien if you run into this I believe I fixed it on my squeel fork

Comment: @Damien It was quickly merged. Hurray

Comment: Ha! Fantastic. Hopefully this will inspire others to contribute fixes than find workarounds. I'm certainly guilty of the latter.